# Unity 2018.1 WebGL fails on CommitUpdate using icsharpcode.sharpziplib

Tags: unity-game-engine, c#-4.0, zip, unity-webgl, icsharpcode

I have been working on a WebGL project using Unity 2017. We use `ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip` to generate zip-files and upload them to our server. This worked well using the following code:

```
public string ZipFiles(List<string> files)
{
    // create new zip file
    string zipPath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/upload.zip";

    try
    {
        // prepare
        FileStream fsOut = File.Create(zipPath);
        ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Create(fsOut);

        // fill
        zip.BeginUpdate();

        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            zip.Add(file, Path.GetFileName(file));
        }
        Debug.Log("Zip before commit");
        zip.CommitUpdate();
        Debug.Log("Zip after commit");
        zip.Close();
        Debug.Log("Zip after close");
        fsOut.Close();
        Debug.Log("Zip filestream closed");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.Log("Exception Zip: " + ex);
    }
    // finish
    return zipPath;
}
```

Now with the update to Unity 2018.1 we also updated to .Net 4.6 - everything is working fine in Editor.

Using the WebGL build the application fails on `zip.CommitUpdate();`

Error Log only displays:

```
NotSupportedException: Encoding 437 data could not be found. Make sure you have correct international codeset assembly installed and enabled.
  at System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding (System.Int32 codepage) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 

(Filename: currently not available on il2cpp Line: -1)
```

I think this a very useless error log...

The zip-file in the file-system gets uploaded, but is empty. Files are available: one xml and two json files. (Already made a check with `File.exists` earlier...)

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out!

I cloned the  [github project SharpZipLib](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib) and created the DLL with .Net Standard 2.0 as ClassLibrary. 
I replaced my existing DLL with the self created DLL.

Then I made little changes to the code: before we were using a FileStream to generate the zip-file. Now we use the `ZipFile.Create(string path)` variant.
Also we use a `DiskArchiveStorage` refering to the zip-file. ("on disk")

```
public string ZipFiles(List<string> files)
{
    // create new zip file
    string zipPath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/upload.zip";

    try
    {
        // prepare
        ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Create(zipPath);

        // fill
        DiskArchiveStorage myDisk = new DiskArchiveStorage(zip);
        zip.BeginUpdate(myDisk);

        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            Debug.Log("ZIP: add " + file);
            if (!File.Exists(file))
            {
                Debug.Log("File not found!");
            }
            zip.Add(file, Path.GetFileName(file));
        }
        zip.CommitUpdate();
        zip.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.Log("Exception Zip: " + ex);
    }

    // finish
    return zipPath;
}
```

Now it is working like before!

Answer (score 1):

In the .NET 4.6 class libraries, it might be the case that encoding 437 is in an embedded resource. By default WebGL builds do not include embedded resources to save size. You can enable embedded resources for WebGL like this:

https://forum.unity.com/threads/enabling-embedded-resources-with-webgl.326069/

I'm not certain this is the issue, but it is probably worth a try. If this does not work, it is a bug we should investigate from the Unity side. Please submit a bug report.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately this did not do the trick... still getting the same error and the application fails on `CommitUpdate()` - I tried to use `ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip` in a clean project. Here it works. So I think this is not a Unity bug.

Comment: Argh! Forgot to set .Net 4.x in the player settings. With .Net 4.x seleted the WebGL fails using a cleand project, too!